# what if i never update to minor updates

Tags: updates, update-manager

in Vista, I have turned updates totally off; I update when I feel like it; and I will be to blame if I don't update when there has already been a cyber world war (which is sarcastic for "I update when I feel like it"). What if I do that in Linux? By linux I definitely mean Ubuntu.

For downvoters:
I don't want to update my ubuntu everyday, I only want to update to major long term supports, what is my liability?

Answer (score 2):

Failing to apply updates regularly will cause your machine or devices to be more vulnerable to recently-discovered security flaws.  Take the recent Heartbleed vulnerability for instance: if you weren't watching the news and you didn't update, any SSL-protected resources may have their private keys stolen.

If you're only running your desktop machine on your LAN behind a good firewall, there's less risk than in other scenarios and the Heartbleed example becomes a little drastic.  On the other hand, you're more vulnerable to viruses and malware if you're not regularly applying updates.  Viruses targeting Linux are less common than those targeting Windows, but I think you should still be careful.

At the end of the day you have to be the judge of whether or not you are willing to take the security risk involved in not regularly applying updates, because only you know the sensitivity of your data and how important it is to you to keep it private.